# Celery duplicate workers on long tasks

Tags: python, django, celery

Task run once and long celery tasks(5-6 hours long) starts to duplicate itself approximately every hour up to 4(concurrency parameter).

Logs:

```
[2016-08-19 07:43:08,505: INFO/MainProcess] Received task: doit[ed09d5fd-ba07-4cd5-96eb-7ae546bf94db]
[2016-08-19 07:45:44,067: INFO/MainProcess] Received task: doit[7cbc4633-0687-499f-876c-3298ffdf90f9]
[2016-08-19 08:41:16,611: INFO/MainProcess] Received task: doit[ed09d5fd-ba07-4cd5-96eb-7ae546bf94db]
[2016-08-19 08:48:36,623: INFO/MainProcess] Received task: doit[7cbc4633-0687-499f-876c-3298ffdf90f9]
```

Task code

```
@task()
def doit(company_id, cls):
    p = cls.objects.get(id=company_id)
```

Celery worker start with `--concurrency=4 -Ofair`, broker - Redis 3.0.5 version.

Python package versions:

```
Django==1.8.14
celery==3.1.18
redis==2.10.3
```

Comment: https://github.com/celery/celery/issues/2481

Comment: @UsmanMaqbool it helps, thanks!

Comment: @chinskiy did you replace a broker from Redis to RabbitMQ?

Comment: @AbbasovAlexander No. For me helps to increase visibility timeout parameter.
http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/getting-started/brokers/redis.html#visibility-timeout